# Issue with parallel arrays and reading integers / doubles from file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have an issue with parallel arrays and getting the program to read integers and doubles. For example, I have a text file with these values:

1234 99.58

5678 1854.99

The first number being an account number and the second number being the balance of the account. I'm not sure how to get them into a parallel array (int[] accountnumber, double[] balance) while going down the list of ideally 10+ accounts and balances.

I've tried filling the arrays separately without success, which doesn't feel like the most efficient method possible. I've tried breaking down the "(int = 0; i < maxAccts; i++)" so I could use the "i" variable for both without resetting it.

```
    public static int readAccts(int[] acctNum, double[] balance, int maxAccts, File myinput, Scanner inputFile) throws IOException {
    maxAccts = 0;
    while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        //Test for reading integers accurately
        //System.out.println(inputFile.nextInt());
        maxAccts++;
        inputFile.nextLine();}

    //Test for maxAccts
    System.out.println(maxAccts);

    acctNum = new int[maxAccts];
    balance = new double[maxAccts];
    Scanner AccountFiller = new Scanner(myinput);
    while(inputFile.hasNext());{            
    int i = 0;
    while (i < maxAccts) {
            acctNum[i] = AccountFiller.nextInt();
            balance[i] = inputFile.nextDouble();
    i++;}
    //for (int i = 0; i < maxAccts; i++)

    System.out.println(acctNum[1]);}
    return maxAccts;
}
```

I keep getting this error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
```

At this point, I don't know why it's going wrong. In my head the cursor in the document should be right after the integer (account number), and I'm not getting an issue with that part.

Comment: You are just checking that `inputFile.hasNext()` then using `balance[i] = inputFile.nextDouble()`. Try changing the condition in your second while to `inputFile.hasNextDouble()`. You may also run into a similar issue because you are not checking if your other scanner, `AccountFiller` has a next or not.

Comment: This feels like a school assignment so I am not sure how much flexibility you would have when reading in the data, but if I were doing this I would read the document line by line and then split each line on the space. The result would be a string array with 2 elements and then you could just parse each element to an Int or a double and store in the appropriate array.

Comment: `inputFile` likely skips over some of the doubles in the file during the first while loop, so it runs out when running `inputFile.nextdouble()` in the next loop. Are you sure you should be using the same scanner?

Comment: You use maxAccts as an input, set it to 0, then set it to the max accounts, then return it.  Why is it even an input instead of a local variable?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to fix your while loop

Your second while loop looks like this:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext());{
```

Which has a semicolon between the while and the curly brace, which means that the body of the loop is empty and after it is done looping, you run the code inside the curly braces.
The loop should be like this:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
```

This causes the error of reading the nextDouble since we just consumed the scanner's source until there is no next.

You might also want to check again how you want to read the file, since the first part doesnt really make much sense to me, it appears you just skip over all ints found in the file (while counting how many times you skip)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, that was a really stupid mistake on my behalf. The first section before the array portion was to tally the number of accounts total, there probably is a better way to do it that I'm not thinking of or don't know with my current knowledge.